# Need to use wkhtmltopdf in docker node:alpine image

Tags: node.js, docker, wkhtmltopdf

I have image docker image node:alpine , need to use wkhtmltopdf in some part of my API services. Here is my docker file

```
FROM node:alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json .
# For npm@5 or later, copy package-lock.json as well
# COPY package.json package-lock.json .

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

remember i already have wkhtmltopdf container on my docker

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from its repo on github and call the binary within your container:

`RUN curl -L https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz | tar -xJ`

The above downloads and extracts it in your active working directory in your docker image.

Comment: i have installed the wkhtmltopdf binary in my project root directory, how can i call it into my container ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your project structure and also what you are trying to achieve? If wkhtmltopdf is in your project root, and if you are mounting or copying your project root in a container, then you should be able to call it from your code the same way you do it outside of docker environment.

Comment: i have multiple node running container on docker, i have API service to convert html into pdf. i have extracted above binaries in my working directory but its not working